# can you use LIKE and AND together

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to get all the orders that have been placed on 2016 and on 2018

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate LIKE '2016%' AND '2018%';
```

But it only show the results of 2016

I tried

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate = date('2016-%m-%d');
```

But it returns a empty screen, I understand that's because there isn't a row with a value of '2016-%m-%d'

I also tried with 'IN' and its the same result as '=' At this point I have tried with different operator but the results are the same. either error or a white screen.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to repeat the whole expression on both sides of `AND`:

```
WHERE OrderDate LIKE '2016%' AND OrderDate LIKE '2018%';
```

But that can't be true for any value. Nothing can start both with `2016` and `2018` at the same time. Maybe you wanted `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: I m triyng to get all the orders between 2016-01-01 and 2016-12-31 but also the orders made between 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31

I tried
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN "2018-02-01" AND "2018-02-28";
but when I try to add 2016 also all i et is error.

WHERE OrderDate LIKE '2016%' AND OrderDate LIKE '2018%' gives me an  'Execution finished without errors.' but its an empty screen

Comment: @MaikolRojas: Have you read the whole answer? The last paragraph is important, too.

Comment: It's a query to extract quantum entries that exist in two states at once.